# MySql DELETING a Customer & their orders from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to delete a customer and their orders from 3 different tables by CustomerID with phpMyAdmin using a routine (cID). 
My table structure is below as an image:
[Tables structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhuEH.png)
Primary keys are CustomerID, OrderID, ProductID.

Table: orders

- OrderID
- OrderDate
- CustomerID

Table: customers

- CustomerID
- CustomerName
- Customer Address

Table: products

- ProductID
- ProductDesc
- ProductPrice

Table: assigned

- ProductID (foreign key)
- OrderID (foreign key)
- Quantity

Query below:

```
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO customersdeleted SELECT * FROM customers  
WHERE CustomerID = cID; DELETE assigned 
FROM assigned INNER JOIN orders  
ON assigned.OrderID = orders.OrderID 
WHERE orders.CustomerID = cID;
DELETE FROM customers WHERE customerID = cID; 
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT * FROM customers; SELECT * FROM customersdeleted;   
END
```

I have been trying for ages to get this query to work and delete the customer and their orders by CustomerID and insert them (once deleted) into the customersdeleted table I also created.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you have some issues when yo create the tables;
i am giving you a simple solution of your code:

```
create table order(
orderId varchar(10),
order_date date,
customerId char(7),
primary key(customerId)
);
create table customers(
customerId char(7),
customerName varchar(30),
primary key(customerId),
foreign key(customerId) references order(customerId),
on delete cascade

);
```

N:B:on delete cascade will delete the customerid from all the tables if you delete the customer id from your order table.so then change your query such that you have to only delete the customerid of order table others will automatically delete as they are foreign keys.

Comment: I am not able to get that solution to work with phpmyAdmin. I am trying to write a query that will delete any OrderId associated with a CustomerID along with the CustomerID. So any records of that customer and their orders would be deleted from the database. Also the associated OrderID needs to be deleted from two tables (assigned and orders) and CustomerID from the customers table. Will ON DELETE CASCADE achieve this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: yeah. you have to use on delete cascade if the reference of the foreign key get deleted,the foreign key tuple will also be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the query to work and add the deleted data to a specific table. I was only missing after DELETE assigned, ***orders***. See below.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO customersdeleted SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE CustomerID = cID;
DELETE assigned, orders 
FROM assigned
INNER JOIN `orders` ON `assigned`.`OrderID` = `orders`.`OrderID` 
WHERE `orders`.`CustomerID` = cID;
DELETE FROM `customers` WHERE `CustomerID` = cID;
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT * FROM customers;
SELECT * FROM assigned;
SELECT * FROM customersdeleted;
END
```